# how to show different url in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

How can i change view like "www.abc.com/welcome" in browser but actual path is "www.abc.com/welcome.aspx".

And when i type "www.abc.com/welcome" then will go path "www.abc.com/welcome.aspx" but still view like "www.abc.com/welcome".

I have try this code on web.config below but got error:Unrecognized configuration section urlMappings

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
  <add url="~/welcome.aspx" mappedUrl="~/welcome" />
</urlMappings>
```

I wonder still got other way?

Comment: Hi, i would suggest using routing which you can use even in web forms. Have look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202(v=vs.90).aspx for directions. Its pretty easy to setup and to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where did you get the information about this `urlMappings` section?  It's not supported by default by IIS or ASP.Net.

I think you might want to look at the [UrlRewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/).

With this it's trivial to setup url rewrites like the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a URL rewriting module, you need to make sure which version of IIS you will be running on before something like "/welcome" will work. IIS6 doesn't support extensionless URLs by default. You'll need to have an ISAPI filter running for it, or you'll need to run on IIS7.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use *routing* [How to: Use Routing with Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

You will need to register the `UrlRoutingModule` and the `UrlRoutingHandle`r handler to be able to use routing feature (more details could be found in the article above).

And then in global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.Add("BikeSaleRoute", new Route
    (
       "bikes/sale", 
       new CustomRouteHandler("~/Contoso/Products/Details.aspx")
    ));
}
```